# Swift 5.1/Cocoa: How do I register a method in a class other than self as a notification observer?

Tags: cocoa, swift5

I can establish an observer callback by passing in `self` and referencing a method within the same class:

```
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default
                          .addObserver(
                            self,
                            selector: #selector(notificationReceived),
                            name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Hello"),
                            object: nil)
    }

    @objc func notificationReceived() {
        print("I have received the notification!")
    }

    //...
```

In the above case, `notificationReceived` is called when the notification is posted. However, I can't do the same if I want to register a callback belonging to another class:

```
class Another {
    @objc func notificationReceived() {
        print("I have received the notification!")
    }
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let observer = Another()

        DistributedNotificationCenter.default
                          .addObserver(
                            observer,
                            selector: #selector(observer.notificationReceived),
                            name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Hello"),
                            object: nil)
    }
```

Why doesn't the above work? What do I need to do to register a method belonging to an object other than `self` as the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with "another class". It has to do with object lifetimes.

You are saying `let observer = Another()` and in the next instant the method `didFinish` comes to an end and your instance of Another, `observer`, vanishes in a puff of smoke. So there is no one for the notification center to talk to. There is no chance for any notifications to arrive; the observer is gone before that can happen.

(Indeed, it used to be that you would *crash* for doing this, because you left the notification center with a "dangling pointer". Now you don't crash, but nothing happens.)

That isn't the case with `self`, not because `self` is "the same class", but because it's the app delegate, which lives for the entire lifetime of the app.

Comment: The *reason* that `DistributedNotificationCenter` allows `observer` to disappear in a "puff of smoke" is that the `Center` is only retaining a `weak` reference to `observer`, so once the last reference outside the `Center` disappears, the `observer` is released.  You can see that in the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/distributednotificationcenter/1414136-addobserver , which says "The receiver does not retain notificationObserver."

Comment: @BobGilmore And until relatively recently, `weak` meant non-ARC weak, hence my point about crashing. It was crucial to unregister an observer before the observer was deallocated. Nowadays, `weak` means ARC-weak and there is no such penalty.